# Returning first matching row Improving query performance

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I have a database of public records with over 1 million rows. I need to query the database using a users fullname and Birthdate. The query would look like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TexasBexarCountyMisdemeanorPublicRecords 
WHERE  ([FULL-NAME] = 'EXAMPLELASTNAME, EXAMPLEFIRSTNAME') 
  AND (BIRTHDATE = '1989-10-18 00:00:00')
```

Currently this query takes 2 minutes and 45 seconds to be completed successfully. Unfortunately because of the data structure and the information the user provides, i cant think of any other way of querying the database.

The purpose of this query is to provide a list of records pertaining to a single user. These records define their ownership by having a users full name and a date of birth. All the columns have string values. It is also possible that a user has more than one record.

1. This query is extremely inefficient. Is there a better way to search through the records looking for a FULLNAME and BIRTHDAY Match?
2. I was thinking of stopping the search after a first match however that would not be useful for users that have several records.
3. I already have a primary key column and can find records using that ID quickly. However there is no way I know that ID when the user is logging in for the very first time. Thus I need to search through the records using their first last name and date of birth and then save those id's for future reference.
4. If I add more criteria to the search would that make it more efficient? If I pass values for SEX, RACE, ETC.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Is it MySql or Sql-Server?

Comment: Did you consider to add an index, which optimizes your query, e.g. an index in the columns FULL-NAME and BIRTHDATE?

Comment: I have an Unique identifier however I had not thought of adding an index to other columns. Ill look into that, thanks @ThomasPhilipp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It returns fast on ID because its indexed. Index the fields you are searching on and also consider covering indexes if appropriate.

Comment: Dang!  You beat me to it by five seconds!

Comment: Thanks @Joe C Ill look into adding index

Comment: WOW I am just amazed on how much you can learn from StackOverflow. Thanks @Joe C now my query is instant.